# Unable to configure C++, GDB, & VS Code harmoniously. Getting error message: `Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected`

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure the debugger on visual studio code but am failing to get it to work. I've installed MING-W64 and the c/c++ extension on visual studio code and when I run my code, here is the output when I try debugging with a breakpoint at the line that says  `cin >> x >> y >> oper;`  :

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
```

Here is the code I am trying to execute.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculator 
{
    public:
    int Calculate(int, int, char); 

};
int main() 
{
    int x,y,result; 
    char oper; 
    cout << "hello! I'm a calculator!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter num1 operator num2: " <<endl;
    cin >> x >> y >> oper; 
    Calculator c; 
    result=c.Calculate(x,y,oper); 
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl; 

    cin.ignore(); 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int Calculator::Calculate(int x, int y, char oper)

{
    switch (oper)
    {
        case '+':
            return x+y;
        case '-':
            return x-y;
        case '*':
            return x*y;
        case '/':
            if(y!=0)
                return x/y;
        default: 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Below is my tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ -g Calculator.cpp -o Calculator", 
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }, "problemMatcher":"$gcc"

        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": " ${workspaceFolder}/Calculator",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I solved it by:

(ON LINUX)

installing gdb:

```
sudo apt install gdb
```

Then reload the window / close and reopen, and try again. This should fix it.

(ON WINDOWS)

*Create a c_cpp_properties.json file with the following configuration:*

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            //the path to your c++ folder in the mingw, in my case:
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++"

        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++"
            ]
        },
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

*then, create a launch.jason file with those specifications:*

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/file_name.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        //miDebuggerPath, normally as folow:
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Mingw\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
         //optional, if you want to automatically build it
        "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
]
```

}

*You will also need a taks.json file:*

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++ -g file_name.cpp -o output_name.exe",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

*EDIT: 
Previously I've just told how to fix it on Linux, added how to configure on Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

---

## Configuring GNU, GCC, GDB, Linux, & VSCode

---

##### This answer addresses improperly configured C++ projects that are being developed inside of the V.S. Code editor.

- Some of the issues that arise are likely to be, **Breakpoints not breaking**.
- **Error Messages** that complain about Symbols, file-paths, non-existent files,
- **unconfigured Target Architecture**. No path-set for Shared Libraries.
- I will also touch on `Makefiles`, as many people experiencing the following are, like myself, building their projects w/ the `GNU Make CLI` & `Makefiles`

---

##### THE COMMON ISSUE THAT OCCURS WITH ISSUES:

> "Let me start off by saying that this issue drove me halfway to insanity, which is quite unnecessary considering its only a configuration issue. The reason its difficult to solve is due to a lack of good information, and there being good amount of miss information that covers this topic."

###### WILL THIS SOLUTION WORK FOR YOU?

> It is likely that the following solution is what you are looking for. This answer addresses the common problem that less experienced developers face quite often: _Improperly Configured Projects" — I am a student, therefore, admittingly, I should know best what an inexperienced developer might face most often. The problem here is a lack of correct configuration.

---

###### Read the following, and see if it sounds like your project. You will then know if your in the right place:

---

##### First off, lets talk about what you are experiencing, to make sure that your issue is the same issue as what the question's author, and myself, have had to deal with.

###### 1️⃣ Your Platform, Tooling & Env should be setup w/ the following software:

1. DEV-ENV:        ***`VS Code v1.62.1`***
2. PLATFORM:    ***`Linux/WSL`***
3. LANGUAGE:    ***`C/C++`***
4. COMPILER:    ***`GNU's GCC-10/G++-10`***
5. DEBUGGER:    ***`GDB/Mi`***

---

###### 2️⃣ Breakpoints Failing to Break During Runtime Execution:

- You should be experiencing an issue where your breakpoints fail to break during the execution, and debugging of your program. In my case, GDB/Mi didn't even acknowledge that there was ever a breakpoint set.

---

###### 3️⃣ Receiving the following `ERROR MESSAGE`:

```
01 >  /*
02 >  --------------- OUTPUT-CONSOLE: "ERR MSG #1" --------------- */
03 >
04 >  For help, type "help".
05 >  Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
06 >  Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
07 >  =cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
```

---

> ###### *The ERR MSG above is what the author of the question was getting, and its what lead me to find his issue, and his question about it. I don't know if he was only getting that error, but I was getting receiving the following error message below, in unison with the error message above.*

---

```
01 >  /*
02 >  --------------- OUTPUT-CONSOLE: "ERR MSG #02" --------------- */
03 >
04 >  For help, type "help".
05 >  Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
06 >  =cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
07 >  Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
08 >  Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded
```

---

##### At this point you should know if your in the right place. I assume if your still reading, your right where you should be.

##### SOLUTION:

---

First off, lets make sure our debugger, and our editor, are both being verbose with their logging information:

###### add the following to your ***`launch.json`*** configuration:

```
    "logging": {
        "moduleLoad": true,
        "programOutput": true,
        "trace": true,
        "traceResponse": true,
        "engineLogging": true
    },
```

### LOL!

The **[VS Code Documentation (HERE)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_debug-the-debugger)** actually refers to the above configuration as the...

#### `Debugger of the Debugger`

You don't need to turn them all on, to be honest I have them all on, because its not exactly clear to me which one is printing what output, I am sorta new to this too, which is why I am able to walk you through this. I have just thoroughly addressed this issue over a period of 3 long grueling days.

They will invoke GDB to log more information, and to log more often. I got extremely helpful troubleshooting support after setting the properties above to true. You can see there output each-time you run the debugger in the debugger output window (not to be mixed up with your terminal).

What the output, and read the messages printed in the `debugger output` every single time you run the debugger, whether it is successful at debugging & breaking or not.

The fix isn't difficult, and its **LITERALLY SPELLED OUT FOR YOU**. If you look at **ERROR MESSAGE #1 @ LINE-06** you'll see the following line printed as part of the `GDB` Error Message:

##### `06 >  Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.`

If you got your logging working as I pointed out above, and are seeing the error message that I am referencing, then you should be able to add the following to your `launch.json` file, and your most of your problems should go away.

```
    {
        "targetArchitecture": "x86_64",
    }
```

or

```
    {
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
    }
```

The later worked for me, but from what I read other people used the x86x64 with success more often.

---

If you are getting error simultaneously, there is a good chance that you have multiple things wrong. One such case is if you don't add a return statement to main. This will cause the following error

##### POP UP NOTIFICATION IN VS CODE:

```
Unable to open 'libc-start.c': 
Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/build/glibc-
eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c' 
(Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-remote:
//wsl+ubuntu-20.04/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c').
```

This **`ERROR NOTIFICATION`** doesn't feel good when it happens, but from what I understand its harmless and easy to fix.

###### As you can see, I am on WSL. If you have access to libc from your machine, you may not get this error, however, thats almost worst. This error is caused from stepping beyond the scope of the project, and into code that makes up the various libraries used by core parts of the C & C++ languages. In truth, I do not know exactly what the code is you step into, but I know that there is no reason, and will never be a reason, to step into any code — especially unknown code — by steeping past the end of your projects main function with a debugger. Its, bad, its not good.

Fix it by placing a return statement at the end of main, however; I have heard of people stepping past the main return statement. The safest route, is to make sure you have a return statement in main. Set the return statement to `return 0;` and add a breakpoint to the same line as the `return 0;` statement.

---

##### Do you use Make?

If your using make, like I was. You will need to start with a totally new project, as make adds much to your project, and caches data in the editors history. VSCode does allow you to clear its history/history-cache by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and typing `CLEAR EDITOR HISTORY` and then selecting `CLEAR EDITOR HISTORY`. Some people said that worked for them, but I couldn't get it to work until I started a new project.

You also need to make sure that you compile using the `-g` flag, so that your project is compiled for debugging. All of this little things can cause a headache.

Much of this issue shows why p reconfigured IDEs are still preferred over editors by big projects.

---

###### if I sound harsh, I just want to note:

> It was also spelled out for me and I didn't get it. Hard lesson learned, I need to pay attention to error messages more, and do a better job interpreting there meaning.

---

HERE ARE TWO ISSUES ON GITHUB THAT HELPED ME IMMENSELY

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2376
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues/188

FYI, the other answer on this page is just a Copy & Paste from:

[C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux%20Using)

...and whereas it is a good thing to configure your project as the guide suggest, most people with this issue outlined above, are going to experience it after following the guide, and failing to succeed, therefore; I find that answer to be useless IMO.